# Load all objects of specific type from Ravendb and use include to load related documents

Tags: database, ravendb

I am trying to load all the elements of type **Cause** from ravenDB and also to **Include** related documents contained in each specific object (in order to improve performance). For instance, I am trying to mix the following two calls together:

To load all documents:

```
 _session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Cause>()
         .WhereEquals(x => x.IsDeleted, false)
         .WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()
         .ToArray();
```

To Include related documents into the call:

```
_session.Include<Cause>(x => x.ValueIds)
        .Load(idCause);
```

Does anyone know how I could approach this problem?

**Edit** For anyone stumbling on this problem one possible solution is as follows:

```
_session.Query<Cause>()
        .Include(x => x.ValueIds)
        .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
```

**Edit 2**
I encountered a different problem but it is related to the above. If I wanted to add an additional element into the Include call, does anyone know how I could achieve this? I tried the following, but I don't think it is the proper way of doing this because additional calls to the database are being made:

```
_session.Query<Cause>()
        .Include(x => x.ValueIds)
        .Include(x => x.GroupIds)
        .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **In addition to the solution you mention in 'Edit1'**,
you can also use:

```
var results = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Cause>()
     .Include(x => x.ValueIds)
     .WhereEquals(x => x.IsDeleted, false)
     .ToList();
```

2) Using **Multiple Includes** on the same operation (as you are doing in '**Edit2**') is correct. 
See: https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch02/Ch02.md#includes

Comment: I am sorry but I wasn't very clear in my question. I am trying to load multiple entities at once that are of different types, that is the reason why I am doing two different includes at once. The approach you suggested in the edit seems to refer to the case when the entities are of the same type. Thanks for your answer!